# Groovy JDK 11 disable the WARNING message

Tags: groovy, java-11

When I run **Groovy 2.5.3** on **JDK 11** its giving warning message:

```sh
groovy -e 'print "hi"'
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/home/user/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/lib/groovy-2.5.3.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

***Is there an option to disable this warning message?***

Comment: It seems that there's open PR for this issue: https://github.com/apache/groovy/pull/811/

Comment: @Opal Thanks looks like I have to wait for another groovy release.

Comment: You can set the `GROOVY_TURN_OFF_JAVA_WARNINGS` environment variable to `true` until we fix the underlying code.

Comment: Thanks Paul,  now its giving another warning `WARNING: package sun.awt.windows not in java.desktop`

Comment: I presume you are on *nix? Can you try removing "--add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.windows=ALL-UNNAMED" from your startGroovy shell script. It's needed when on MS Windows OS but we haven't made it conditional when it finds it is on cygwin or similar.

Comment: now warning message gone. Thanks Paul.

Comment: @PaulKing I see that the PR has been merged, can you advise which stable release for groovy has the fix for this issue?

Comment: @phalgun Perhaps this update will help you:
https://opencollective.com/friends-of-groovy/updates/progressing-towards-groovy-3-0-0-with-greatly-reduced-illegal-access-errors

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the Java warnings with `GROOVY_TURN_OFF_JAVA_WARNINGS` as a temporary fix:

```
$ GROOVY_TURN_OFF_JAVA_WARNINGS=true groovy -e 'print "hi\n"'
hi
```

Answer (score 2):

This is still an issue in `Groovy 2.5.8`

I'm on macOS. I chose to fall back to **Java 8** (In homebrew, do a ***brew cask install adoptopenjdk8***) and the warnings went away. I understand that is is not desirable if you need a newer JDK (I do not)

Answer (score 2):

The current stable version [3.0.x](https://groovy.apache.org/download.html) of Groovy is reported to fix this issue, see [GROOVY-8339](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8339) for the detailed discussion.

Answer (score 1):

To disable warnings either by upgrading groovy version to large than 3.0.0 or by passing `--add-opens` to the JVM.
unfortunately it requires a lot of modules to be opened check the following [commit](https://github.com/apache/groovy/commit/92bd96fcdfe35e502987e1846715a08a45620db1)