# Grails: disable warning message

Tags: grails, groovy, java-11

I have the following error message when I execute `grails -v` on grails 4.0.0.RC1

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
```

From the question [Groovy JDK 11 disable the WARNING message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52930532/groovy-jdk-11-disable-the-warning-message), I can see that setting an environment variable indeed removes the warning from `groovy -v`. However the grails CLI seems unaffected.

How to remove that warning from grails?

Thanks.